# Postgres NATURAL as attribute is represented as "natural"

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap

I'm working with openstreetmap data and import it with tools into a postgres database. One key term in openstreetmap is [natural](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:natural).

When importing this data, a column name in the postgres database table is `natural`.
The issue is, when reading the table in some clients, the attribute `natural` is represented as `"natural"` which leads to issues.

Is there a way to store `"natural"` as `natural` OR help the client to read it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

natural is a reserved keyword in postgres:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html

keywords have to be quoted if they are used as identifiers.  If possible, choose a different name.